# Show $t^5-5t+1$ has no multiplicities

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

**Problem**

Show that $f(t)=t^5-5t+1$ has no repeated roots.

**My initial idea**

I write $f$ in terms of linear factors $(t-\alpha_1)...(t-\alpha_5)$ where all the $\alpha_i$ make up the five roots of $f$. I’d like to show that each possibility of there even existing multiplicities in the factorization leads to a contradiction. The following statements are all that is necessary to prove the original question without loss of generality and after renumbering the $\alpha_i$. The first case would be that $f(t)=(t-\alpha_1)^2(t-\alpha_2)(t-\alpha_3)(t-\alpha_4)$. The second would be that $f(t)=(t-\alpha_1)^2(t-\alpha_2)^2(t-\alpha_3).$ The third case would be that $f(t)=(t-\alpha_1)^3(t-\alpha_2)(t-\alpha_3)$, and so on proving the rest of these possibilities until they are all exhausted out.

**My question**

Obviously, this is time consuming and there’s likely a better solution. I would like any suggestions on how to solve the problem quicker without this exhaustive method.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Remark**

I tagged irreducible polynomials and gcd/lcm because I am not sure if any suggestions would have to do with them, yet I still suspect that they would.

Comment: A root with multiplicity $\gt1$ would be a root of the derivative as well.

Comment: That allowed me to prove it. I saw this result in my book and studied it more. Thank you for the push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(t)=t^5-5t+1 \implies f'(t)=5t^4-5, f'(1)=0,f'(-1)=0, f'(i)=0, f'(-i)=0$ but $f(1), f(\pm 1), f(\pm i)$ are non-zero. So there exist not even a root with multiplicity 2.

Edit: For multiplicity of orfer $m$ at $x=a$ we must have $f(a)=f'(a)=...f^{(m-1)}(a)=0$. $k(x)=(x-1)^4$ has multiplicity of order 4 at $x=1$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem if you use discriminant of polynomial P = resultant of P and P' (its derivative). You may look at definition of resultant there - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant

$$ \phi (A, B) = \begin{vmatrix} 
a_0      & 0           & \cdots & 0          & b_0        & 0              & \cdots & 0       \\
a_1    & a_0       & \cdots & 0           & b_1     & b_0           & \cdots & 0  \\
a_2    & a_1     & \ddots & 0           & b_2     & b_1         & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots  &\vdots   & \ddots & a_0        & \vdots   &\vdots       & \ddots & b_0  \\
a_d       & a_{d-1} & \cdots & \vdots   & b_e       & b_{e-1}     & \cdots & \vdots\\
0          & a_d       & \ddots &  \vdots  & 0          & b_e          & \ddots &  \vdots  \\
\vdots  & \vdots   & \ddots & a_{d-1}  & \vdots  & \vdots      & \ddots & b_{e-1}   \\
0          & 0          & \cdots  & a_d       & 0           & 0              & \cdots & b_e   
\end{vmatrix},$$

where $A$ and $B$ - polynomials with coefficients $a_i$ and $b_i$.

In our case:

$$\phi (P, P') = \begin{vmatrix} 
1&0&0&0&  5&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&  0&5&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&  0&0&5&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&  0&0&0&5&0\\
-5&0&0&0&  -5&0&0&0&5\\
1&-5&0&0&  0&-5&0&0&0\\
0&1&-5&0&  0&0&-5&0&0\\
0&0&1&-5&  0&0&0&-5&0\\
0&0&0&1&  0&0&0&0&-5\\   
\end{vmatrix} = -796875.$$

This determinant is not zero iff there are no repeated roots.  It is easy to calculate in wolfram mathematics.